# Why did 'the system identify' a high quality post 'as possible spam' in review audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, spam, first-posts

I was reviewing posts in the First Posts review queue and I got a review audit. Link to the review audit: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1093198. I found it was an audit by clicking on the link of the answer. There was this text mentioned in the audit (visible before passing the audit and after passing the audit):

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review
> carefully

But the post was not really spam.

Screenshot of the audit:

[image: Screenshot of the audit after passing]

Why was the post 'identified as possible spam' by the 'system'?

By the way, what does the word 'system' refer to? Is it a bot?

---

Why is the question also marked as 'possible spam'?

[image: Screenshot of the question in audit]

Comment: Related: [Good review audit has “possible spam” warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223569)

Answer (score 7):

It wasn't identified as spam, on the contrary, it was identified as high quality and that's why it was used in a review audit. Review audits are there to stop "robo reviewing": people who just blindly click through a review queue in order to get a badge. Yes, such people actually exist and they're why we have review audits in the first place.

In this case, the idea was to see if you were paying attention. If you weren't paying attention, you could have marked that as spam which would have made you fail the audit. Since you *were* paying attention, you correctly marked it as "looks good" or whatever, and you passed the audit.

Comment: I guess "*review auditr*" is a typo. Please correct it. Hmm.. But why does the question need to be marked as 'possible spam'? And why can't they remove "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" after failing/passing the audit (or probably strike the text)? I marked it as "No Action Needed".

Comment: @technastic_tc yes, typo, thanks. The question does NOT need to be marked as possible spam. As you correctly point out, it is not spam. As for the "our system..." message that isn't part of the post. It is only shown to you, when you look at the audit. The actual post has no such message: [grep: Show ALL lines before a match](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284775).

Comment: Hmm.. I understand that it's only part of the audit. And the text in this case was used to trick the reviewer. Once the review is done, the text could be striked for clarification. This will help anyone else opening that review audit link (in later point of time) understand that the text was a trickery. BTW, some useful info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/728668

Comment: @technastic_tc nobody else will ever open that review audit. The audits are generated for each user. The only chance someone else visits it is if they go through your history or click on the link you gave. And then it's useful to see the message so they can see what you saw.